# how to use indexpath.row outside the table function

Tags: ios, swift

my tableview is

```
  struct country : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let capital : String
    let region : String
  }

  class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var countries = [country]()

    let color = UIColor()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self


        let jsonurl = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
        let url = URL(string: jsonurl)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            do {
                self.countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([country].self, from: data!)

            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
          }.resume()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func redButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
          let index = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
           let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: index)
     }
}

 extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
     section: Int) -> Int {
        return countries.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: 
     IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row].name.capitalized

        let cellnumber = indexPath.row

       return cell
    }
```

now I want to use cellnumber or indexpath.row in my button action. I do this but i can not get indexpath.row
I want to do when I pressed the button at that time the odd number cell of the tableview 's background color change in red and even number cell 's background color change blue. But problem is out side tableview function I get only one value not whole number of array. In above program if I print cellnumber we get whole number of cell.

Comment: Did you create a cell custom class ?? also where the button exists ??

Comment: on redButtonAction method which cell index you want to access ?

Comment: no i did not create a cell custom class. button exists outside the tableview.

Comment: i want  to access all cell index not only selected cell index.

Comment: what you want to access all cells ? not clear . On button click which cell you want on which condition ?

Comment: Do you want only visible cells index?

Comment: i want to do when i pressed the button at that time the odd number cell of the tableview 's background color change in red and even number cell 's background color change blue.

Comment: but problem is out side tableview function i get only one value not whole number of array

Comment: in above program if i print cellnumber we get whole number of cell.

Comment: @sohan123 
you  should use global flag variable like var isNeedColorChange : Bool = flase and need to true on button Action then reload table view,
And put condition of background color in cellForRow

Comment: i can edit my code. now please help me.

Comment: On button click you should reload the table view, and in the [tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt] method you check the indexpath.row is odd or even and change the cell color accordingly.

Comment: This will crash in case of any network or service problem -> `data!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table view cell is reusable and you can get only visible cell's indexPath so you should reload table view on clicked of button and need to put condition if you want to change color or not in cellForRowAt

Code for change row color on button clicked

```
struct country : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let capital : String
    let region : String
}

class ViewController : UIViewController {

    var countries = [country]()

    let color = UIColor()
    var needToChangeColor : Bool = false

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self


        let jsonurl = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
        let url = URL(string: jsonurl)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            do {
                self.countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([country].self, from: data!)

            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
            }.resume()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func redButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.needToChangeColor = true
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController :UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
        section: Int) -> Int {
        return countries.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath:
        IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row].name.capitalized
        if needToChangeColor == true {
            if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. @Jatin Kathrotiya

Answer (score 0):

The very basic solution would be adding a `tag` for your button in `cellForRowAt`. It will work in case you have only one section.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row].name.capitalized

    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

Now in your method

```
@IBAction func redButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let index = IndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
      let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: index)
   }
```

Unfortunately this approach will not be so efficient if you add any complexity to your `tableView` layout.

Comment: There is no button in a UITableViewCell

Comment: Then the author needs  to explain what behavior they’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sh_Khan how you know ?

Comment: @vivekDas I don't speak about implementation but the above code won't compile only when the op use **as! CustomCellClass**